# "Set Smooth" and "Subdivide Mesh" geometry nodes nasty interaction

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to "Set Shade smooth" and "Subdivide mesh" of geometry created within a GN group.

As soon as I apply the "Subdivide mesh" node, the smoothing effect progressively disappears, depending on subdivision level applied (the higher the level the more the smoothing disappears).

No problems with a similar non subdivided mesh, instead.

Below the GN group and the result.
[image: Geometry nodes]

[image]

I've tried to force the smoothing before and after the subdivision, but in vain.

Is there any ways to obtain the smoothing of GN created and subdivided mesh?

Comment: It's working as intended. You're subdividing the mesh, but not with catmull-clark. You're simply adding more edges while mantaining the same 'low poly' shape, so you have more faces but they're flat, and so shade smooth doesn't smooth it enough because the avarage normal still looks 'low poly', even though it isn't.
Long story short: use subdivision surface, not subdivide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the subdivision surface node, not the subdivide node. The difference is like switching catmull-clark switch in the subdivision modifier.
Subdivide is just simple interpolation on the flat surface of each rectangle of your sphere, which will make your edges sharper the finer your subdivide gets.